# splice always delete last item in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, splice

I'm sure the problem is very simple, but I have stack in it for hours.

I created an app that can add or remove  to upload files.

When I click delete button, it always delete the last items.
I have tried to solve it by adding `:key="key"`, and it changes nothing.

What may be wrong with my code?
Here is the codepen:
https://codepen.io/shanyulin/pen/RwaWaZy?editors=1010

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group clearfix" v-for="(event, key) in events" v-bind:key="key">
  <input name="attachment[]" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf" type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  <button @click="deleteEvent(key)" class="btn btn-danger">x</button>
</div>
<button @click="addEvent" class="btn btn-dark">+</button>
</div>
```

Js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            events: [{}],
           }
    },
    methods: {
        addEvent: function() {
            let quantity = this.events.length;
            if (quantity < 6) {
                this.events.push({
                    index: ''
                });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        deleteEvent: function(key) {
            let quantity = this.events.length;
            if (quantity == 1) {
                alert("Please upload at least one file.");
            }
            if (quantity > 1) {
                const confirmed = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
                if (confirmed) {
                    this.events.splice(key, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

Comment: it actually did delete the desired index. the issue is just how it is being re-rendered when it reacts to the changes of the variable `events`, when you try to do the `select file`, it never save the order, it is just sitting temporarily, so when the for-loop renders the input field again,  it will look like it removes the last one but it actually just ignores if the field has a selected file or not.

check my js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/s2f06bc9/

Comment: @KarlL Thanks for your explanation, yes, I have noticed that it deletes the desired index but with wrong target. It's clear to see what runs behind the screen!

Comment: bind the loop instead with an explicitly declared unique key, see changes here https://jsfiddle.net/s2f06bc9/

Comment: @KarlL Thank you Karl, can you further explain why you would not to create unique key?

Comment: i just used the index as an example, as you already have it in your object, also it would make sense by naming it `index` and would be redundant to use another `unique key` . but seeing the answer below, that's a good way of doing it as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array index is not reliable for `key`. If you have an array with three elements, keys are `0,1,2`. When you remove second one, keys are `0,1`, not `0,2`.

You need to provide unique key for each element.

```js
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
        return {
            events: [{}],
            uniqueKey: 0,
           }
    },
    methods: {
        addEvent: function() {
            let quantity = this.events.length;
            if (quantity < 6) {
                this.events.push({
                    index: '',
                    key: this.uniqueKey++
                });
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        },
        deleteEvent: function(key) {
            let quantity = this.events.length;
            if (quantity == 1) {
                alert("Please upload at least one file.");
            }
            if (quantity > 1) {
                const confirmed = confirm("Do you really want to delete?");
                if (confirmed) {
                    this.events.splice(key, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group clearfix" v-for="(event, key) in events" v-bind:key="event.key">
  <input name="attachment[]" accept="image/png, image/jpeg, application/pdf" type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg">
  <button @click="deleteEvent(key)" class="btn btn-danger">x</button>
</div>
<button @click="addEvent" class="btn btn-dark">+</button>
</div>
```